# ¿Cómo diferenciar 80 y 2 de 82?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

En realidad pensaba hacer esta pregunta en el exchange de inglés "How to differentiate between 82 and 80 2", pero describiendo la pregunta me di cuenta de que en realidad esto también pasa en el español, asi que decidí empezar preguntandolo aqui.

Lo que ocurre es que 82 se lee "ochenta y dos", exactamente igual que "80 y 2".
 ¿Tiene el español alguna buena forma de diferenciar estos dos casos?

Por ejemplo:

> -¿Cuántos caramelos de limón y de menta tienes? 
>   -Ochenta y dos.

En este caso puede entenderse que se tienen 80 caramelos de limón y 2 de menta, pero también que solamente se tienen entre los dos 82 caramelos (por ejemplo, 40 de limón y 42 de menta.)

Comment: Supongo que lo normal sería que quien responda dijera"ochenta de menta y dos de limón" o hiciera alguna diferencia en la entonación para dejar en claro lo que quiere decir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La única forma de diferenciar en el discurso hablado "82" y "80 y 2" es por medio de la prosodia, es decir, introduciendo entonación y pausas donde parezca conveniente para enfatizar la diferencia.

En castellano si bien se escribe *ochenta y dos*, habitualmente se dice en una sola palabra (fonológicamente hablando), como si fuese *ochentaidós* (a veces *ochentidós*), por lo cual marcar claramente la acentuación prosódica de *ochenta* bastaría para señalar que estamos nombrando el número 80 aisladamente.

También hay que tener en cuenta que el ejemplo es forzado. En la práctica muy poca gente dirá algo como eso. La forma más natural de contestar la pregunta sería:

> *Ochenta de limón y dos de menta.*

Answer (score 4):

No he logrado dar con la pregunta de [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/) que mencionaste, pero seguramente la mejor solución en castellano, igual que en inglés, sea decirlo con unas cuantas palabras adicionales para evitar algún tipo de ambigüedad:

> ¿Cuántos caramelos de limón y de menta tienes?
>
> Pues tenemos unos cuarenta de limón más unos cuarenta y dos de menta, o sea ochenta y dos caramelos de ambos sabores en total.

Todo esto es un problema, si de hecho es un problema, en la lengua hablada  y no en la escrita.

La misma ambigüedad puede ocurrir en inglés con números como 105 si se pronuncia *“a hundred **and** five”* — ¿son dos figuras o una sola? Debe  resolverse de la misma manera.

Comment: Es normal que no encuentres la pregunta. En ningun momento dije que llegué a formular la pregunta. Solo dije que antes de hacerla ahí decidí hacerla aqui. Pensaba que las respuestas podrían ser las mismas asi que es mejor preguntarlo en un solo sitio y dependiendo de las respuestas me decidiría a preguntarlo en el exchange de inglés o no. De todos modos gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: I suppose one could always reverse the order of the two nouns and say _dos y ochenta_

Comment: @mdewey your answer is pretty good!. If I were you I would post your comment as an answer for my question. You could win some upvotes.